# Trasmisión datos de llamada http a componente hijo

Tags: angular, typescript, http

Hola tengo problemas para pasar los datos de una petición http a un componente hijo.

Primero obtengo los datos utilizando dos servicios y esa parte funciona bien.

servicio-principal.service.ts

```
llamadaGet(url2: string, datosLlamada: any) {

    return this.http.get(ServicioPrincipal.myUrl+url2, datosLlamada);

}
```

servicio-secundario.service.ts

```
getDatos () {

    const myParametros = {parametro1: 'texto1', parametro2: 'texto2'};
    
    return this.sesionServ.peticionGet('textoUrl/texto', myParametros);
    
}
```

Despues los llamo desde un componente y haciendo un `console.log` los datos se muestran, pero los envió a un componente hijo y ahí no se ven(en el componente hijo).

componente1.component.html

```
<componente-hijo [datos]="myDatos">
```

componente1.component.ts

```
constructor(private servicioPrincipal: ServicioPrincipal, private servicioSecundario: ServicioSecundario) {

    this.ServicioSecundario.getDatos()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data); // Aqui si se muestran los datos
      this.myDatos = data;
    });

}
```

componenteHijo.component.html (Aquí es donde no se muestran los datos)

```
<p *ngFor="let registro of _datos">{{registro.campo1}} {{registro.campo2}}</p>
```

componenteHijo.component.ts

```
@Input() datos: any[] = [];
ngOnChanges() {
  console.log(this.datos);
}
```

Si envió datos en bruto al componente hijo(sin hacer una petición http) si se muestran.

Edición: Al hacer el ngOnChanges() los datos se muestran en el hijo pero no pasan a la vista.

Agradecería vuestra ayuda.

Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: No veo motivos para que no funcione el código que has puesto. ¿Has probado a añadir un método `ngOnChanges` en el componente hijo y comprobar que se llama después de obtener los datos?

Comment: He editado la pregunta con las pruebas que dices.

Comment: ¿Y no hay ningún error en la consola?

Comment: no, el array se muestra bien con el console.log(dentro del ngOnChanges) de la variable pero no entiendo porque no pasa a la vista, es como si no tuviera data binding la variable, podría intentar forzar a copiar los datos a otra variable en el ngOnChanges pero no me parece la forma correcta de hacer las cosas en un framework como angular.

Comment: Tengo creado un ejemplo [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pawer13-angular-comunicacion?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) donde el paso por Inputs funciona sin problema, sin necesidad de hacer nada cuando se actualiza el Input... tiene que haber algo fuera de ese código que muestras que impide el funcionamiento y se nos está pasando por alto.

Comment: Ese código no es igual porque trabaja con observable(en vez de una llamada http) y lo llama directamente desde el componente hijo. En mi código si le mando una variable en bruto del padre al hijo si la lee pero al ponerle la llamada real no va.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente descubri que el eroor no estaba relacionadado con la llamada http, sino con que los datos que se muestran en la vista estan filtrados mediante una función y que esta debe llamarse con cada cambio de los datos de origen para que estos se actualicen:

componenteHijo.component.html

```
<p *ngFor="let registro of _datos">{{registro.campo1}} {{registro.campo2}}</p>
```

componenteHijo.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.filtro();  
    
}

filtro() {

   this._datos = this.filtrado.transform(this.datos,this.palabra);

}

ngOnChanges() {

    this.filtro();

}
```

Y para que sea mas eficiente

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    if (changes.datos && changes.datos.currentValue) {

      this.filtro();

    }

}
```